# Using a different method signature in Java

Tags: java, methods, generic-list

The following two methods compiles fine and do what they stand for.

```
public int returnArray()[]
{
    int a[]={1 ,2};
    return a;
}

public String[] returnArray(String[] array[])[]
{
    return array;
}
```

---

According to this method signature, can't we somehow have a method signature like the following?

```
public <T>List rerurnList(List<T> list)<T>
{
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

This method is intended to return a `java.util.List` of generic type. **It does not compile**. It must be modified as follows for its successful compilation.

```
public <T>List<T> rerurnList(List<T> list)
{
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Can't we have a method signature like the first cases, in this case?

Comment: Why would you want to complicate things like that? In fact, why do you complicate things by writing things like in the two first examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason Java lets you define arrays like in C, adding the `[]` modifier *after* the variable or method name. That, however, is not possible with generics.

Generic type arguments *have* to be declared right with the type, because *they are part of the type descriptor*. Arrays should also be declared that way, as *they are also part of the type descriptor*.

In order to understand why the compiler does not let you write things that way (and why it *shouldn't* let you write things like in the first examples), we need to break it down to pieces.

---

```
public int returnArray()[] { ... }
```

- `public`: Visibility declaration
- `int`: Return type, integer
- `returnArray`: Method name
- `()`: Argument list (empty)
- `[]`: Whoops! the return type is actually an arrayof what we said before

---

This is even better:

```
public String[] returnArray(String[] array[])[]
```

- `public`: Visibility declaration
- `String[]`: Return type, an array of strings
- `returnArray`: Method name
- `(String[] array[])`: Argument list...

  - `String[]`: Type of the argument, array of strings
  - `array`: Name of the argument
  - `[]`: Whoops! argument type is actually an array of what we said before
- `[]`: Whoops again! return type is actually an array of what we said before

Foot note: Don't do this, specify the types only in the types. Instead of `String[] array[]`, use `String[][] array`.

---

Now that the array thing syntax is clear, and I hope you understand why it *should* be wrong, let begin with the generig thing:

```
public <T> List<T> rerurnList(List<T> list) { ... }
```

- `public`: Visibility declaration
- `<T>`: This method uses generic type `T`
- `List<T>`: Return type, a generic `List` of `T`
- `rerurnList`: Method name
- `(List<T> list)`: Argument list

  - `List<T>`: Argument type, generic `List` of `T`
  - `list`: Argument name

Comment: The last part of the answer is really the more helpful, last 2 lines.

Comment: Reordered. That's now at the top :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer your question: the syntax you're trying for the method that fails compilation is definitely wrong because of the `<T>` placed between the parameter list and the method body:

`(List<T> list)<T>{`

This is simply not valid Java syntax. That's not how you mark a generic method. You already marked the method as generic by putting the type parameter - `<P>` - between the method access modifier and its return type.

Comment: @Darkhogg Because simply it's not valid Java syntax. It doesn't mean anything in the Java Language, therefore it's illegal. That's not how you mark a generic method.

Comment: Andrei, that comment should really be part of your answer, given that the question is indeed `"why"`, not `"how"`.